# Edit data from database in form when using radio button

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I have a database with some information which i then show using php and javascript
If i click on edit a javascript form opens up and i can edit the shown information. This all works great but instead of an input field (in which i show the data currently inside of the database) i would like to use a radio button.

So i need to make a radio button with the values Yes and No and if the information inside the database = 0 i want to show no and 1 to show yes

When using an input field i see yes or no (depending on what is stored inside the database) how can i use a radio button in this scenario.

my input field looks like this

```
<input type='text' class='input' name='test_" +id+ "' value='"+test+"' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have html like this:

```
<form name="yesnoform">
    <label for="no">No</label><input value="no" type="radio" name="yesno" id="no"/>
    <label for="yes">Yes</label><input value="yes" type="radio" name="yesno" id="yes"/>
</form>
```

you can use this code to select correct radio button:

```
var fromDB = 0;
document.yesnoform.yesno[fromDB].checked=true;
```

If you want yes radio button first:

```
<form name="yesnoform">
    <label for="yes">Yes</label><input value="yes" type="radio" name="yesno" id="yes"/>
    <label for="no">No</label><input value="no" type="radio" name="yesno" id="no"/>
</form>
```

then use this:

```
var fromDB = 0;
var value = fromDB === 0 ? 1 : 0;
document.yesnoform.yesno[value].checked=true;
```

Here is JSBin: https://jsbin.com/fijiteruba/edit?html,js,output

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for youre input. Shamefully it doenst seem to work in my particular situation. I have pure text and a button which calls the form which i later generate using javascript. Below is my form (its stripped but this is the idea)

Comment: function makeForm(id,mydiv,test){
   
                var div = document.getElementById(mydiv);
                var divHTML = "<form action='test.php' method='POST' name='formervaring'><table  width='400'> <tr><td width='100'>test: </td> <td width='300'><input type='text' class='input' name='test_" +id+ "' value='"+test+"' />  </td></tr>  <input type=submit> </form><hr>";

                div.innerHTML = divHTML;

                }